# JAVA Regex Character recognition

Tags: jdeveloper

I am using p{L} to accept chinese alphabet in our code, i tested this in eclipse and the system showed success result whereas when the same was used in Oracle Jdeveloper, system is throwing a failure. This is the code snippet, i am using.
Please provide me an answer.

```
            public static final String VALID_CHARACTER_PATTERN = "[\\p{L}0-9_*]*";

            public static final boolean hasRestrictedChars(String suspectedString) {
                    return !suspectedString.matches(VALID_CHARACTER_PATTERN);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    boolean check = hasRestrictedChars("你好");
                    if (check)
                            System.out.println("InValid String");
                    else {
                            System.out.println("Perfect");

                    }
            }
```

Comment: "system is throwing a failure" - does that mean you get the wrong result e.g. false instead of true, or that you get an exception/error/crash?

Comment: yes, False not any exception. "Invalid String" is the output in jdeveloper where as for the same input "Perfect" is the output in Eclipse. @shree.pat18